# Iphone OpenAL looping sound not restarting after pause

Tags: iphone, loops, audio, restart, openal

I'm using something like this to start a looping sound:

```
if (m_pSource ==  OS_INVALID_SOUND)
{
    alGenSources(1, &m_pSource);AL_CHECK
    alSourcei(m_pSource, AL_BUFFER, m_pBuffer);
    if (Is3D())
    {
        SetMinDistance(m_minDistance);
        SetMaxDistance(m_maxDistance);
    }
    if (IsLooping() && !IsStreamming())
    {
        alSourcei(m_pSource, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);
    }
}
if (m_pSource !=  OS_INVALID_SOUND)
{
    alSourcePlay(m_pSource);AL_CHECK
}
```

then at some point I use:

```
alSourcePause(m_pSource);AL_CHECK
```

to stop the sound and then:

```
alSourcePlay(m_pSource);AL_CHECK
```

once again to restart it. Everything works as expected except the sound is not restarting after the last play. Anyone has any idea what can cause this ? or if I do something wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it seems that even if I delete the source, the minDistance, maxDistance, pitch modifier and other parameters are saved somewhere (when I create a new source sometimes has set up some of the parameters previously set).
So the best way is to set everything right after the source is created.